# Windows Basic Theme seems to make gpu related stuff slower

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, aero, dwm

When I have the windows basic theme (the one that disables aero), smooth scrolling (in firefox and chrome- enabled in the flags section) seem to run worse - lower fps - than if I was using the Aero DWM. Why is this? Shouldn't it be even faster?

Also, the cpu usage when smooth scrolling is dramatically higher with the basic theme.

Also, windows classic theme is even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design, because the Basic and Classic theme use the **CPU** instead of the GPU. If you don't like Glass, only turn the Transparency off but keep the composition improvements of the DWM.

Comment: So turning off DWM changes the rendering to the CPU even within the window borders? Within chrome, under the gpu information, it still says that canvas etc is "hardware accelerated". How come its not using the gpu?

Comment: what do you mean with "even within the window borders"?

Comment: What i mean is that the DWM manages the window contents as well?...As far as gpu acceleration is concerned

Comment: yes, the Program can use HW acceleration to draw its content, but Windows must manage all shown Windows and this is slow with DWM turned off. See the picture under "Desktop Composition" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2006/03/05/544314.aspx

Comment: Ok, but how come a game's, such as minecraft, doesnt fluctuate based on dwm, but chromes smooth scrolling fps does?

Comment: games run in full screen and Windows don't need to redraw other elements.